# SAS proc surveyselect don't sort output

Tags: sorting, random, sas

I'm using a `PROC SURVEYSELECT` statement to get random numbers from a set of integers. SAS then returns the sampled integers but in ascending order, and I need them to remain in random order. How would I either randomly mix the output from the `SURVEYSELECT` statement, or just get the statement not to sort? I can't seem to find any option that lets the statement just output in the order that it randomly selects.

Here's the code:

```
proc surveyselect data=data noprint
method=srs
n=numOfSamps
seed=123
out=outputSet
run;
```

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your data look like?  Is OUT= in the same order as DATA=?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to random sort your final stratified sample you can use `ranuni()` and `proc sort`.

```
data data;
    set data;
    rn = ranuni(12345);
run;
proc sort data = data; by rn; run;
```

Comment: This was the solution I found to be the easiest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random permutation of integers size n of x you can use PROC PLAN.  I don't know how that would fit with your SRS but then you don't tell the whole story do you?

```
proc plan;
   factors x=10 of 100 random / noprint;
   output out=x10;
   run;
   quit;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the default of SURVEYSELECT, if you have just a single SRS.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(7);
  do _order = 1 to 1e6;
    intnum = floor(rand('Uniform')*1e9);
    output;
  end;
run;


proc surveyselect data=have noprint
method=srs
n=10000
seed=123
out=outputSet;
run;
```

As you can see from the included _ORDER variable, it's not sorted in any way - it still retains the initial ordering (and there's nothing special about that variable).

Now, if you are doing stratified SRS, which is implied by your use of a dataset name in the above code (but you leave the details of that out), it will get sorted, and you need to include the _ORDER variable or something similar, and then re-sort by that variable to return to your original order.